# Increasing padding in plotly pie chart hoverlabel - javascript

Tags: javascript, css, plotly, plotly.js

I'm trying to increase the padding of the hoverlabel property for pie charts using below method but seems not working. Has anyone tried this use case or is there any other way to do it..

```
 hoverlabel: {
                        bgcolor: 'white',
                        bordercolor: '#e7e7e7',
                        font: {
                            color: 'black',
                        },
                        padding: {
                            t: '20',
                            b: '50',
                            l: '0',
                            r: '0'
                        },
                        borderwidth: 2
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you give more details on your library version ? possible a JSFiddle will do.

Comment: I am trying to look into the following API reference - https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#pie

Comment: @abhijat_saxena I'm using the latest version https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/releases/tag/v1.54.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS to expand the legend box, and then move the hover elements.

```
.legend .bg {
  rx: 10px;
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}

.legend .scrollbox {
  transform: translate(10px, 7px);
}
```

Not a perfect solution but it works.

Answer (score -1):

`Plotly Pie Chart` does not support padding property in `hoverlabel`

Reference - https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#pie-hoverlabel

However you can customize your hover label by using `hovertemplate` property
https://plotly.com/javascript/hover-text-and-formatting/